# iOS; Unsupported Pixel Format

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, camera, format, arkit

My Unity app uses the Camera feed for multiple systems that the app uses; such as Vuforia, ARKit, and just general Camera feed input.

The issue I'm having is that each one of these requests a different Pixel Format, which seems to cause an issue for the ARKit. This requires YUV, and I don't know how to natively switch the camera pixel format back to this. So I get this error when I try and launch ARKit after the others;

> 2017-08-21 08:51:38.749452+0100 ar_app[399:105849] [Sensor]
>   Unsupported pixel format: 875704438
>
> 2017-08-21 08:51:38.749876+0100
>   ar_app[399:105849] [Session] Session did fail with error: Error
>   Domain=com.apple.arkit.error Code=104 "Unsupported capture session
>   configuration."
>
> UserInfo={
>       NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Make sure that the correct device and format are being used for capture.,
>
> NSLocalizedDescription=Unsupported capture session configuration.,
>
> NSLocalizedFailureReason=Input device and/or format of the provided capture session are not supported for the given
>   configuration. }

At least, thats what I think the issue is; that it's not getting the format in YUV. Any help would be much appreciated.
.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[YUV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV) is a color space, there are multiple formats.

> ar_app[399:105849] [Sensor] Unsupported pixel format: 875704438

`875704438` translates to `420v` ([NV12](https://www.fourcc.org/pixel-format/yuv-nv12/)) or [kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1563591-pixel_format_types/kcvpixelformattype_420ypcbcr8biplanarvideorange):

```
kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange = '420v'
```

So you actually have a YUV pixel format, specifically the biplanar with video range.

The ARKit [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/displaying_an_ar_experience_with_metal#2891878) do mention the biplanar YUV format but not the type of range:

> The pixel buffer’s contents are encoded in a biplanar YCbCr (also called YUV) data format

However the Unity ARKit Plugin does a check for [kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1563591-pixel_format_types/kcvpixelformattype_420ypcbcr8biplanarfullrange) in [didUpdateFrame](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/unity-arkit-plugin/src/053e5b4d716e44223cec5dec53ed57eaef9455f3/Assets/UnityARKitPlugin/Plugins/iOS/UnityARKit/NativeInterface/ARSessionNative.mm?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#ARSessionNative.mm-486):

```
 if (CVPixelBufferGetPlaneCount(pixelBuffer) < 2 || CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType(pixelBuffer) != kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange) {
        return;
    }
```

So in conclusion it might not like the fact that it's not full range, but I have no easy way to test it. Maybe you can try forcing full range if the camera and the other modules support it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How would I force full range? Im not a native xcode developer.

Comment: @OliverJones Sorry, me neither. The setting doesn't seem to be exposed in ARKit. Vuforia lets you set [YUV](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/Working-with-the-Camera#How-To-Access-the-Camera-Image-in-Unity) but it doesn't say what kind of YUV format it uses. And this is assuming the underlying problem is what ARKit actually reports and not a side-effect of something else (camera device not released, some other bug).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure not to use .jpg images anymore. iOS wants you to use .png images. I had the same warning/ error in Swift 4 and XCode 9 Beta.

Comment: How do I do this? Its calling the native ARKit.